# Class hierarchy, get property by priority

Tags: c#

I have class hierarchy. Each classes may has configuration object. I need to get final configuration - if the configuration has the first class (A), it will be used this one. If the configuration has the second class (B), it will be used this one.

**Here is an example:**

A:     -         **C23**

B:     -        -

C:     **C2**       -

D:     C1       C4

Result is C.Config1.C2 and A.Config2.C23. In short, I need to use first not null constant.
Here is my code:

```
enum Config { C1, C2, C3, C4 }

enum Config2 { C21, C22, C23, C24 }

class Configuration
{
    public Config Const1 { get; set; }
    public Config2 Const2 { get; set; }
}

class A
{
    public Configuration Config => CombineConfigs();

    public B B { get; set; }

    private Configuration CombineConfigs()
    {
        Config c1 = B.Config != null && B.Config.Const1 != null 
                    ? B.Config.Const1 
                    : B.C.Config != null && B.C.Config.Const1 != null 
                      ? B.C.Config.Const1 
                      : B.C.D.Config != null && B.C.D.Config.Const1 != null 
                        ? B.C.D.Config.Const1 
                        : Test.Config.C1;
        Config2 c2 = B.Config != null && B.Config.Const2 != null 
                     ? B.Config.Const2 
                     : B.C.Config != null && B.C.Config.Const2 != null 
                       ? B.C.Config.Const2 
                       : B.C.D.Config != null && B.C.D.Config.Const2 != null 
                         ? B.C.D.Config.Const2 
                         : Test.Config2.C21;
        return new Configuration()
        {
            Const1 = c1,
            Const2 = c2
        };
    }
}

class B
{
    public Configuration Config { get; set; }
    public C C { get; set; }
}

class C
{
    public Configuration Config { get; set; }
    public D D { get; set; }
}

class D
{
    public Configuration Config { get; set; }
}
```

How to write better method `CombineConfigs`?

Comment: How can `B.Config.Const1` ever be null? It's an enum.

Comment: Yeah this looks super x/y ish

Comment: @Sweeper because property in Configuration class doesnt have to set

Comment: remove `? : ` plz. It so unreadable OuO

Comment: @bluray Then you need a `Config?` and `Config2?`. Enums are non-nullable by default. `Config` will have a default value of `C1`, for example.

Comment: @Sweeper ok, it is possible set default value to `Config1` and `Config2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be the best approach, but you can use the null-coalescing operators to great effect:

```
var c1 = B?.Config?.Const1 
         ?? B?.C?.Config?.Const1 
         ?? B?.C?.D?.Config?.Const1 
         ?? Test.Config.C1;
```

Though if I understand your question correctly, you should invert the order; if you want the most "derived" configuration, just do:

```
var c1 = B?.C?.D?.Config?.Const1
         ?? B?.C?.Config?.Const1
         ?? B?.Config?.Const1
         ?? Test.Config.C1;
```

Of course, this is kind of horrible, so you might want to think about a different design, especially if you're not really sure how much "depth" there might be.

Also, keep in mind that I dropped the equivalent of your `B.Config.Const1 != null` etc. - these will always evaluate to true. If you want to also have the option of having `B.Config.Const1`, you need to declare it as a nullable value (`Config?`). The old approach for enums has also been to use a guard value as a default, usually with the value `0`. Both have their benefits.

Comment: Enums cannot be null.

Comment: @TanveerBadar ... okay? I'm never testing an enum for null.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. I thought if there was any better option, f.g. use IComparable, IEquatable or something else. because if there are a lot of constants it will be confusing

Comment: Then what do you suppose this `B?.C?.D?.Config?.Const1 ??` is going to evaluate to?

Comment: Do enlighten me. And while on the subject, look up what `false ?? true` will do.

Comment: @TanveerBadar I never test the value of `Const1` against anything. Reread the code in the answer.

Comment: @TanveerBadar `false ?? true` will produce the error "error CS0019: Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'bool'".

Comment: @Sweeper Correct, I couldn't think of a handy enum to illustrate the point. What I meant to write was enumVal ?? enumVal.

Comment: @TanveerBadar That's the exact same thing. But that's not what I'm doing anyway. The types aren't `Config` and `Config`, they're `Config?` and `Config`. If the first operand is nullable, I take the second. If not, I take the first. I don't care about the *value* at all.

Comment: @TanveerBadar [Do you know about this?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-)